# How to remove the default upload capacity limit of 40MB in joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0

I am a new to joomla, I use xampp to install joomla, because the default upload file size of joomla is 40MB, if the file is too large, how to solve it? Is there a way to remove the 40MB default upload capacity of Joomla?

The picture is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD4Z8.png)

Comment: zip or compress your file

Answer (score 0):

Joomla does not restrict file upload size for extension installation. You need to increase the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` PHP variables.

You can do this via cPanel -> Select PHP Version -> Options if you are using cPanel or you may be able to edit the `php.ini` file in the root folder of your website e.g. `/public_html/php.ini` as follows:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
```